# event.srcElement is not working when the class sector is using

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have an issue of using `event.srcElement`. I have written an event handler for a class selector but when I am taking the source element the exact element which I have clicked is not getting the event. Is there any alternative there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

[`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) instead

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
   // The following will get you the DOM element that initiated the event.
   var targetELement = e.target; 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
```

> but when i am taking the source
>   element the exact element which i have
>   clicked is not getting.Is there any
>   alternative there

You mean this:

```
$('#element_id').click(function(){
  $(this).... // it refers to current element
});
```

If you want to get element in to be used in plain javascript, you can do like:

```
$('#element_id').get(0);
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to add e.originalEvent.target instead of e.target (Firefox 10.0.2)